# How to install Kitchen Cabinets on a Drywall?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I have 2 Kitchen cabinets, each 50 CM on 80 CM, they weigh about 10 KG (maybe more? not sure). 
I wanted to hang them on the wall but just discovered it's a drywall, and seems pretty thin. 
It is a 120 CM wide niche that I have in my kitchen (like an inward gap),
on the left side there's a concrete wall, but on the right once again drywall. 
I've heard something about a Rail that might support them (attaching it to the concrete), but I'm not sure how relevant it is when the other side is also drywall. 
Any ideas? 
These cabinets are suppose to be above a Sink, so I can't think of many alternatives for them, ideas in that direction would help as well.

Comment: You don't hang anything aside from perhaps posters on drywall. What matters is what is behind the drywall. If concrete, you'd use concrete screws. If wood studs, wood screws.

Comment: @Asaf: is this what you mean by drywall? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drywall

Answer (score 11):

When installing cabinets, the "go-to" method is to "hang" them on a rail that you install first. The idea is that the rail, being much lighter and less bulky, is easier to put in place, get level, and then screw into the studs. Sometimes it's just one rail, sometimes two; depends on the cabinet system. The rail should be securely screwed into every stud along its length, to provide a solid anchor for the cabinet's weight.

Then, the cabinets will have a complimenting hanger hardware that will allow the cabinet to hang on the rail(s). That's enough to support the weight of the cabinets and what they hold, but you should still secure the cabinets to the rail, and thus to the wall, with screws through the backing and/or the back edge of the cabinet side panels. Again, how this works depends on the cabinet system; most cabinets have a pretty flimsy backing, but pre-drilled holes to put screws into the rails behind. Then, you put some trim around the back to hide any gap caused by the rail hardware, and you're done.

Comment: define stud please

Comment: -1 - Question is `How to install Kitchen Cabinets on a Drywall?`  - where in your answer do you say anything about drywall? type of studs/ wieght distribution... so it does not rip out of the dry wall.. you know?

Comment: @ppumkin The point is that you shouldn't hang cabinets from drywall...they need to be attached to studs.

Comment: studs? like in screws? i dont think thats good. what about butterfly screws? surely thats the better option as it holds on to a larger area of the drywall? i think you should improove your answer please..

Comment: @Asaf @ppumkin: A stud is a vertical member of a buildings wall in a light-frame constructed building, they can be either wood or metal.  Or a registered animal retained for breeding (but please don't hang your cabinets on this type of stud).

Comment: @ppumkin: Seriously? You would use a toggle bolt (butterfly anchor) to hold hundreds of pounds of cabinet and contents off of the drywall layer? No. You attach the cabinet to the vertical studs BEHIND the drywall, which are designed to support hundreds of pounds of load (thousands actually, but that load is the weight of the house on top of the wall, not what's hanging off the side of it). Drywall maxes out at about 50 pounds. Try hanging a cabinet from toggle bolts next time and let me know how it turns out. Now please remove your downvote.

Comment: NO! As a person who has no experience with this- I have no F* what your answer is about- it confused me even more.. i Googled dry wall studs and it shows me screws.. i don't know what a stud is..?! I never blinking hung a cupbaord on a drywall.. fix your answer then ill remove -1 - your answer is weak mate.

Comment: ... Because a "drywall stud" is another word for a light-duty anchor for mounting light objects to drywall with screws, when you can't or don't want to center the screw on the wooden studs behind it. Look here: http://www.finehomebuilding.com/how-to/articles/anatomy-stud-framed-wall.aspx. The images are of the wood "skeleton" of studs and plates behind your drywall. The vertical timbers are "studs". Excuse my frankness, but if you do not know what I am talking about when I say "stud" in terms of home maintenance, then mounting cabinets is not a DIY job for you. Pay a pro.

Comment: Isn't that just called a French Cleat?

Comment: @ppumkin if every answer had to write a definition for every building termed used within no one would read the answers.

Comment: maybe its just me - but i don't understand anything you write or what you mean.

Comment: @Asaf: The definition of stud: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud